# Best way to display image after user select one

Tags: php, html, image, select

Im wondering what is the best way to display an image after a user select one of the categories on the selection:

```
<form method="post" action="../user/posting.php">
        <input type="text" name="title" required placeholder="Title"/>
        <textarea name="body" rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Details....."></textarea>
        //Here is where the selection of the icon is
        <select name="stat_icon" required>
            <option name="fire" value="fire">Fire</option>
            <option name="traffic" value="traffic">Traffic</option>
            <option name="construction" value="construction">Construction</option>
            <option name="crash" value="crash">Crash</option>
            <option name="weather" value="weather">Weather</option>
            <option name="robbery" value="robbery">Robbery</option>
            <option name="deviation" value="deviation">Deviation</option>
            <option name="police" value="police">Police</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="location" required placeholder="Location">
        <input type="file" name="img_stat">

        <input type="submit" value="Stat!" />
</form>
```

I don't know what is the best way to display the image, if I have to upload the image first or I have to only set some if statements to select the image is in one of my folders. Im using php, html and for database mysql. Any suggestion

Comment: Do your images correspond to those `value` attributes, like `fire.jpg`, `traffic.jpg` etc. ?

Comment: yes each image has unique value

Comment: Okay, I've given a PHP based answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can display an image using JQuery, ofcourse you have to upload all images to your images directory first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imageSelector").change(function() {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("#imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='path/to/your/image/" + src + ".jpg'>" : "");
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="imageSelector" name="stat_icon" required>
        <option name="fire" value="fire">Fire</option>
        <option name="traffic" value="traffic">Traffic</option>
        <option name="construction" value="construction">Construction</option>
        <option name="crash" value="crash">Crash</option>
        <option name="weather" value="weather">Weather</option>
        <option name="robbery" value="robbery">Robbery</option>
        <option name="deviation" value="deviation">Deviation</option>
        <option name="police" value="police">Police</option>
    </select>
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically you should do this ( This suggestion is just an opinion form me , its a way that i use it  ) :

- You should have your imgs already saved in the database ( a name for the img so you can grape it from the folder ).
- When the user pick a catalog from the forms you should have a php code that take the picked data and bring the data that compares with the user choice . i mean by the data is the Imgs .

This is an example from a code that i already have on my website , its easy , i used PDO instead of MYSQLI :

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <select  name="catalog" class="form-control input-lg"  tabindex="1" required>
        <option selected>Pick Your Favorite Catalog</option>
            <?php // Fetching the catalogs names from the database 
                while($FCN = $FetchCatalogsName->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                    { 
                        ?><option value="<?php echo $FCN['catalog'];?>"><?php echo $FCN['catalog'];?></option><?php 
                    }
            ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="filter" class="col-sm-4 form-control input-lg" value="Show Catalog">
</form>
```

Now we have to create the php code that will recive the img catalog from

```
  <?php
        include_once('lib/dbconnect.php');

        if(isset($_POST['filter']))
            {
                $catalog = $_POST['catalog'];
                $FetchImgs = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM picture WHERE catalog = ? "); // Fetching all Imgs that related to that catalog that the user has picked . 
                $FetchImgs->execute(array($catalog));
                if($FetchImgs) 
                    {
                        ?>
                            <?php while($FI = $FetchImgs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                                { 
                                ?>  
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <img src="uploading/<?php echo $FI['Filename']; ?>"> // $FI['Filename'] this will return the name of the img from the database . 
                                    </div>
                            <?php }

                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo "something went wrong ";
                    }
            }

?>
```

Note : in my case the php code is in the same page as the html form and its directly under it .

Comment: what type will be for the image in mysql to upload the file?

Comment: @RobertoViramontes it does not matter , but if you are not going to use GIF you can use PNG or JPG its ok

Comment: ok so i will go like this : you can upload imgs ( png , jpg ) you can pick whatever you want , both its ok too , upload them to a folder using php of course , then in the same code insert the name of the img in the database ( you should have already a table ready for the process ) . when you want to bring imgs from the folder , you can call them by there names just like what i did in my code . this first answer in this Q is good too , but im just bringing imgs from a folder using there names in the database .

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what is the best way to display the image, if I have to upload the image first or I have to only set some if statements to select the image is in one of my folders.

If your sole purpose is to display the image based on the selection, then there's no need to upload any images. The only catch here is, your image names should correspond to `value` attributes of `select` input. Also, image extension should be consistent.

So first of all, remove this line `<input type="file" name="img_stat">` from your `form` and after form submission, display the appropriate image like this:

```
$image_path = '/yourImagePath/' . $_POST['stat_icon'] . '.jpg';
echo '<img src="' . $image_path . '" alt="stat_icon" />';
```

**Note(s):**

- Change `.jpg` as per your image extensions
- Change `/yourImagePath/` and give the appropriate directory path